# Create a Azure VM with unmanaged data disks enabled using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to create a azure vm using powershell so that it would allow to attach unmanaged data disks in future. 
I see documentation on creating but those always create with managed disks

Answer (score 0):

[Example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-powershell-create).

```
nic\network\etc amended

# Create storage account
$storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -AccountName "MyStorageAccount" -Location $location -SkuName "Standard_LRS"

# Add disk
$OSDiskUri = $storageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/vm-disk.vhd"
$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "vm-disk" -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage 

# Create VM
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vm
```

Comment: This creates VM's OS with the unmanaged disk. I am looking for attaching unmanaged data disk (Add-AzVMDataDisk).

Comment: same way, create them and attach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/add-azurermvmdatadisk?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples

Comment: That doesn't work. Because with the above the vm is created by default to use managed data disks. So trying to add unmanaged data disk will error out

Comment: no, with the above the vm would be created with a regular disk

Comment: Correct. I want to create a VM with standard linux OS disk such that it should support adding unmanaged data disk later